# How can i hide some specific category by id for some users in android

Tags: java, android

Below is my code. I want to hide some category for some users on their selection basis.
So anyone can please tell me how can I do this? I want to filter out some categories for users who select veg. I store this data in local storage via sharedprefs, so if user selects veg then I want to hide/filter nonveg items/categories

```
private void GetCategory() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            categoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    
            ApiConfig.RequestToVolley(new VolleyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(boolean result, String response) {
                    //System.out.println("======cate " + response);
                    if (result) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (!object.getBoolean(Constant.ERROR)) {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray(Constant.DATA);
    
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    String pref = prfs.getString("pref", "");
    
                                    categoryArrayList.add(new Category(
                                            jsonObject.getString(Constant.ID),
                                            jsonObject.getString(Constant.NAME),
                                            jsonObject.getString(Constant.SUBTITLE),
                                            jsonObject.getString(Constant.IMAGE)));
    
                                }
                                categoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(
                                        MainActivity.this, categoryArrayList,
                                        R.layout.lyt_category, "cate"));
    
                            } else {
                                lytCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, MainActivity.this, Constant.CategoryUrl, params, false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one flag in `Category` model to know if category data is hide or not and then depending open the selection of veg/non-veg update the list.